# Is it possible to extract info from a client public key in order to create unique folders on server?

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, server, jsse

I am working on an assignment where I am supposed to add client-server mutual authentication to a Java client server application. I have the connection setup and the handshake passes, but I am wondering if I am able to extract info (ie - the serial #) from a client's public key in order to create a unique folder for each client on the server? If so, what would be a good place to look regarding this? Thanks!

Comment: If you authenticate the client, you get its X.509 certificate in which you have its key. After that you can do whatever you want with it in the server. So at this stage, without any code, your question is too broad.

Comment: Note a certificate contains a publickey but is much more. The cert has a serial number, but the publickey does not. Certs from _one_ CA should have unique serials, but not necessarily across multiple CAs, so if you accept (=trust) certs from multiple CAs you can't assume serial is unique. Conversely over time one client will likely use different certs with different serials -- do you want that client to still access their data?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. For transparency I’m using self signed certificates for this project. I generate and add to trust/key stores iaw the JSSE docs. @dave_thompson_085, I didn’t consider that. How would I account for changing certificates?